# Find if substring is in string

Tags: windows, validation, batch-file, cmd

I have a batch file that will prompt the user to provide a user name and password. I am trying to check if the password has the user name in it. I found this example but can't seem to get it to work:

```
@setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
@echo off
SET /P userName=%1
SET /P userPassword=%1
if not x%userPassword:userName=%==x%userPassword% (
GOTO createUser
)else (
GOTO invalidPassword
)
```

I use these values to create a Windows User account:

```
:createUser
net user %$userName% "%$userPassword%" /ADD /PASSWORDCHG:NO
WMIC USERACCOUNT WHERE "Name="%$userName%"" SET PasswordExpires=FALSE

:invalidPassword
ECHO password contains user name
```

Comment: [The Windows command prompt is *NOT* a DOS prompt!](https://scalibq.wordpress.com/2012/05/23/the-windows-command-prompt-is-not-a-dos-prompt/)

Comment: `)else (` --> `) else (`

Comment: This is not a duplicate question.  I am comparing two variables not one like in the quoted duplicate question.  If you would take the time to help with this issue rather than mark it as duplicate you would be more helpful.

Comment: @aschipfl it's only a cosmetic bug. Both `if 1==1 (echo 1)else (echo 2)` with true and with no-true condition  `if 1==2 (echo 1)else (echo 2)` work…

Comment: @JosefZ, thank you; seems I have confused it with `) else(` what I have sometimes seen here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set /p userName=Username:
set /p userPassword=Password:
set replacedUsername=!userPassword:%userName%=!
if not !replacedUsername!==%userPassword% (
    echo invalid password
    pause
    exit
)
net user %$userName% "%$userPassword%" /ADD /PASSWORDCHG:NO
WMIC USERACCOUNT WHERE "Name="%$userName%"" SET PasswordExpires=FALSE
```

After the user inputs a name and a password we take the username as a substring and replace this substring inside the password with an empty string. If the password remains unchanged, we know: the username is not a substring of the password string. Otherwise, the modified password would differ from the original password so we know that it is invalide.

Comment: Passwords are case sensitive, the string replacement isn't. While it isn't a good Idea to have the name inside inside the password, a different unusual casing would lessen (if only a bit) the risc.

Comment: MichaelS, That works thank you.  I also need to make sure that the password is at least 7 character and from 3 of the following groups. 1. English uppercase characters (A through Z) 2. English lowercase characters (a through z) 3. Base 10 digits (0 through 9) 4. Non-alphabetic characters (for example, !, $, #, %).  I think I would have to ask this in a separate questions.

Comment: @joey.coyle Yes, I guess you should post a new question.

Comment: Try username ˙abc˙ and password `a!b^c`  or `a^b!c`. You could disable delayed expansion `call set "replacedUsername=%%userPassword:%userName%=%%"` an properly quote `"%userPassword%"` everywhere. Should work for all `cmd` poisonous characters like `!^%|<>` in a password.